# How to move a file out of /usr/local if I get Permission Denied?

Tags: unix, terminal

I would like to move the file.txt FROM usr/local/file.txt TO /usr/local/folder/file.txt.

However, every time I try I get a permission denied reply.

I have tried:
sudo mv ~/usr/local/file.txt  /usr/local/folder/file.txt

When I got permission denied, I also used chmod and set a 777 just to try and still get permission denied.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[Check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory) whether you have write access to the folder with

```
ls -l
```

Then you can try [changing](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/change-file-ownershipgroups-linux/) the ownership of the folder to your current user.

```
sudo chown -R your_username /path/to/folder
```

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership).

Comment: I used sudo chown -R my_username /path/to/folder and got Operation not permitted. I don't understand this. It should work.

Comment: See this link for what that means:
https://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/032-1.html

you'll need to check the permission of the folder you're writing TO.

Comment: no worries. you can mark your issue as resolved. all the best!